# Relationship between Poisson and Exponential distribution, automobiles arrive per minute

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am struggling to understand the Poisson and Exponential distributions.

> The number of automobiles that arrive at a certain intersection per
>   minute has a Poisson distribution with a mean of 5. Interest centers
>   around the time that elapses before 10 automobiles appear at the
>   intersection.
>
> What is the probability that more than 10 automobiles appear at the
>   intersection during any given minute of time?
>
> What is the probability that more than 2 minutes elapse before 10 cars
>   arrive?

I have the formula P(x,λt) = (e^(-λt)*(λt)^x)/x! and f(x) = λe^(-λx) where λ=5/minute, t is the time, and x is the number of automobiles. I tried integrating f(x)dx from 10 to infinity but got the nonsense answer of e^(-50).

Please explain the Poisson distribution and how to apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, it is easier to first find the probability of the **complement**, that is, the probability that there are $10$ or fewer cars in $1$ minute. The probability that exactly $k$ cars arrive in one minute is $e^{-5}\frac{5^k}{k!}$. Now you can put the pieces together.

For the second problem, use the fact that the number $Y$ of cars in $2$ minutes has Poisson distribution, mean (parameter) $(2)(5)$. We want the probability that more than $2$ minutes elapse before $10$ cars arrive. This is the probability that there are fewer than $10$ cars in $2$ minutes, that is, $\Pr(Y\le 9)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What distribution would I use to approximate the Poisson distribution as a continuous distribution?

Comment: For large $\lambda$ one uses the normal. For continuous analogues of the Poisson, see the gamma distribution.